Is there a way to pull hourly analytics from Azure DevOps analytics view to use in PowerBI
I currently have a PowerBi dashboard that pulls data directly from Azure DevOps using the analytics view. Currently, I have daily data for each developer, but management would like to see the state changes that happen to a user story within the day.
Is there a way to make the data I'm pulling from Azure more granular for my PowerBi board?
Right now, it's showing the state of the user story at the time of the Azure data pull, but if that state has changed multiple time within the day, it does not show that history.
I'm refreshing on the PowerBi side 3 times a day but that doesn't give me any new data.

As suggested below, you can try to enable Automatic page refresh in Power BI. @SarahStanish

You can try to enable Automatic page refresh in Power BI. It can let you custom the frequency of page refresh. You can set to automatic refresh the page every seconds, minutes, hours, etc...
With this feature, it can enable your active report page to query for new data, at a predefined cadence, for DirectQuery sources.

